# Finding coordinates on a scrollable Tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make it so that when you right click, the row is highlighted blue and you can then edit or delete that entry. However, since adding a scrollbar, if the page is scrolled then the selection will be offset.

I have tried to suggested thing of finding the canvasx and canvasy and then using find_closest(0, however when i do that it always returns (1,) no matter what.

Canvasx and canvasy seem local to each label, not the canvas itself

```
from tkinter import *

def RightClick(event):
    #Find widgets on the row that was right clicked
    print(canvas.canvasy(event.y))
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        mouseClickY = event.y_root - root.winfo_y() - widget.winfo_height()
        widgetTopY = widget.winfo_y()
        widgetBottomY = widget.winfo_y() + widget.winfo_height()

        if (widget.winfo_class() == "Label") and (mouseClickY > widgetTopY) and (mouseClickY < widgetBottomY):
            #Highlight that row
            if widget.cget("bg") != "#338fff":
                widget.config(bg = "#338fff", fg="#FFFFFF")

        #Deselect all rows        
        elif widget.winfo_class() == "Label":
            widget.config(bg = "#FFFFFF", fg="#000000")

def onFrameConfigure(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Button-3>", RightClick)

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1080, height=500)
frame = Frame(canvas)  
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) 

canvas.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=5)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw",tags="frame")
scrollbar.grid(column=5,row=1,sticky="NS")

frame.bind("<Configure>", onFrameConfigure)

for countY in range(40):
    for countX in range(6):
        l = Label(frame, text=countX, width = 25, height = 1, bg="#FFFFFF")
        l.grid(column=countX,row=countY+1)
```

Comment: That is waaaaay more code that is necessary, plus your indentation is broken. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, i'll fix that. Just usually when  I post here i'm told to post more code, so I did

Comment: We need only enough code to reproduce the problem, nothing more.

Comment: I updated it, I think that should be better now hopefully

Comment: are you aware of the `winfo_containing` method that will tell you what widget is under a given coordinate? You can give it the root coordinate of the event to get the widget under the cursor.

Comment: Can't believe i missed that. Just added it and it's made the code a lot shorter and cleaner, thanks as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, turns out

```
mouseClickY = event.y_root - root.winfo_y() - widget.winfo_height()
widgetTopY = widget.winfo_y()
widgetBottomY = widget.winfo_y() + widget.winfo_height()
```

should be

```
mouseClickY = event.y_root - root.winfo_y()
widgetTopY = widget.winfo_rooty()
widgetBottomY = widget.winfo_rooty() + widget.winfo_height()
```

OR

I should have used `winfo_containing`, which is a lot neater